# How would one go about a DBA on the internet?

Tags: united-states, internet, international

AFAIK a DBA (Doing business as) needs to be for the target market, not for the place of the business. If I'm wrong, that's that.

If I'm correct, then how would one who is selling over the internet to (almost) anywhere in the world go about using a DBA?

I tagged this question "United-States" but that's only assuming the business is located there and since perhaps this matters. But the question is, as mentioned, about the DBA.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, a trade name registration (which is what a DBA is) is done in the place that is the headquarters address of the business.

It isn't clear why you would choose a DBA over forming an entity, like a single member limited liability company, that provides some legal protections to you.

Comment: `why you would choose a DBA over forming an entity` - not instead, in addition to, for using a different (catchy) name.

Comment: In Delaware, [a DBA is done by county](https://firststeps.delaware.gov/doing_business_as/). But registration of a company is not. So it doesn't seem likely that the DBA is by the company's registered location.

Comment: @ispiro If you have another active address in Delaware where you HQ is located, you would use that. But in the absence of that, you would use its registered location usually. Of course, nothing prevents you from filing in your registered location and also in a location outside Delaware where you actually do business and you have filed a certificate of authority to do business as a foreign company.